# UITextview not showing scrollindicator

Tags: iphone

```
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)]autorelease];

self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-BoldItalic" size:14];

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:2.0/12 saturation:2.0 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1.0];

[self.textView flashScrollIndicators];

self.textView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;

self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

self.textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 1;

self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

What i m missing here to display scrollbar for UITextView or to make textview scrollenabled.

Appreciate help.

Comment: Is your textview scrolling just not showing the indicators, or is it not scrolling at all.

Answer (score 0):

`self.textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;`

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Do you have enough text within the UITextView to permit scrolling?

Comment: i have a long textview content

Comment: Are you setting up your .xib programmatically or are you actually setting things up in Interface Builder?  I was going to say set up an IBOutlet and explicitly set everything for your textViews.  Instead of doing self.textView you could use the name of your IBOutlet. For example if you did the IBOutlet like: IBOutlet UITextView *yourTextView, you could do yourTextView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

Comment: there is no keyboard interaction

Answer (score 0):

The text view is underneath the keyboard. It won't scroll until you've entered enough text to fill all the lines you can't see, and even then you won't be able to scroll it all up into view. To do this properly, you need to listen for the keyboard resize notifications and adjust your text view size to fit the visible space. After creating the text view, subscribe to the keyboard resize notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

then implement those methods:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSValue* val = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[self.view window] convertRect:[val CGRectValue] toView:self.textView];

    CGRect rect = self.textView.frame;
    rect.size.height = CGRectGetMinY(keyboardRect);
    self.textView.frame = rect;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416);
}
```

Finally, if the object that subscribed to the notifications (a view controller, I'm assuming) is going to be disappearing at any point in the lifespan of your app, you'll also need to unsubscribe before it's dealloced. (And even if it's not, do this anyway because it's good practice.)

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    // ...

    [super dealloc];
}
```